# Android - Set TalkBack accessibility focus to a specific view

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

When TalkBack is enabled, is there any way to set the accessibility focus manual to a specific view? For instance, when my Activity is started I want TalkBack to automatically focus on a certain Button (yellow frame around the view) and read its content description.

What I've tried so far:

```
    myButton.setFocusable(true);
    myButton.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    myButton.requestFocus();
```

requestFocus(), it seems, is only requesting input focus and has nothing to do with accessibility focus. I've also tried:

```
    myButton.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
    myButton.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
    myButton.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED);
    myButton.announceForAccessibility("accessibility test");
    myButton.performAccessibilityAction(64, null); // Equivalent to ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS

    AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    if (manager.isEnabled()) {
        AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
        e.setSource(myButton);
        e.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
        e.setClassName(getClass().getName());
        e.setPackageName(getPackageName());
        e.getText().add("another accessibility test");
        manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(e);
    }
```

None of this seems to work.

Comment: "When talkback is started".  Do you mean as in, when talkback is active on my view.  Or, when someone turns on talkback while your view is active?

Comment: Neither. If TalkBack is enabled in the Settings, and an activity of my app is launched, I want the accessibility focus on a certain button inside my activity

Comment: Ah, okay, so when your activity loads, you would like to control which item is initially focused by talkback (android "focus" meaning something different from talkback focus).  For accessibility purposes only.

Comment: I'm curious why you believe you need to do this?  It is generally considered poor practice to shift focus around on users automatically, and in fact, unless properly warned about, can be viewed as an accessibility violation in itself under guideline 3.2 of WCag 2.0.  Though, I'm working on an answer, regardless.

Comment: The target audience for my app are blind people. The main action of the app (taking a picture) is triggered by a particular button. I want the user to have immediate focus on this button when the app is launched, instead of swiping another 6 times before reaching it (which might be considered annoying).

Comment: You SHOULD NOT do this.  This is absolutely a violation of WCag 3.2.  Despite your good intentions, this is inappropriate.  You should let TalkBack interract with your app the way TalkBack interracts with all apps!  By it starting at your Apps label at the top, and them flicking through your app.  I work at an Accessibility company, I have fellow employees who are blind, sitting next to me.  I assure you, they would have the same opinion!  If StackOverflow were accessible, I'd get them in here to back me up :).

Comment: @ChrisCM This could be used when we have a long list, and user wants to go to some list item in the middle (eg, contact list in android, in which we can search by letter). For disabled users, we can define a control which will take the user to some contact list item, hence accessibility focus to that item will be required.

Comment: There are better ways to accomplish what you describe.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: Forcing focus on Activity load to be anywhere but at the top bar is always (okay, always should almost never be said), but really, just don't do it.  It is a violation of all sorts of WCAG 2.0 regulations, including 3.2.1 and 3.2.3, regarding predictable navigation and context changes respectively.  You are, likely, actually making your app MORE inaccessible by doing this.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#consistent-behavior

END DISCLAIMER.

You are using the correct function calls.  All you should need to do is this:

```
myButton.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
```

The problem is more likely the point at which your attempting to do this.  Talkback attaches itself to your activity slightly later in the activity cycle.  The following solution illustrates this problem, I'm not sure there is a better way to do this, to be honest.  I tried onPostResume, which is the last callback the Android OS calls, regarding the loading of activities, and still I had to add in a delay.

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();

    Log.wtf(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onPostResume");

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Button theButton = (Button)WelcomeScreen.this.findViewById(R.id.idButton);
            theButton.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
        }
    };

    final ScheduledExecutorService worker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    worker.schedule(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

You might be able to create a custom view.  The callbacks within view, may provide the logic you need to do this, without the race condition!  I might look into it more later if I get time.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be better practice to add a preference inside my app asking the user whether to put focus on this button? So the default TalkBack behaviour will be used unless the user explicitly sets this preference.

Comment: What I like to do in apps, is to make sure my buttons are reasonably sized, specifically the width.  If a button is wide enough, non-sighted users should be able to find it using touch exploration, instead of having to flick through # times.  Reasonably wide buttons on the center of the screen are easy to find using finger drag motions!  This is the best combination of not violating WCag Consistent Navigation/Context Change guidelines, and maximum non-sighted user experience.

Comment: While this approach may work for the current version of TalkBack, the recommendation we give is to **never** attempt to manually place accessibility focus from an app. You will end up fighting with TalkBack or the user, neither of which is going to provide a good experience.

Comment: Hence, the Disclaimer ;).  Something I've wondered, why isn't that event in protected space, for AccessibilityServices only.  Things that you should "never" do, and I agree this is one of them per WCag (and common sense TalkBack usability) guidelines, seem to fit well into this category...  Just curious, while I've got a Google Rep's attention!

Comment: Yes, the solution presented by ChrisCM works for me.

Comment: @Skywalker10 Thank you for your reply. I was trying to use this to focus a View but it isn't doing nothing. My app is controlled by taps and double taps (i'm listening to hover events to detect taps and touchEvents to detect double taps, because of the Talkback/Explore by Touch). In order for this to work I need that the view be already focused. If the view is not already focused the user needs to touch the view the first time (i need to ignore this hover) and then he can do the double tap (touchEvent) or the tap (hover enter/exit). Did you understand? That code should do the trick right?

Comment: You should open a new question with some code in it. It's kind of hard to guess what could be going wrong without the code.

Comment: @Skywalker10 Thanks for everything. Today I tried this approach with another view (a textView) and it worked. I believe it was not working on the other because it was a custom view and it may be lacking something regarding accessibility. I'll do some tests, if I can't manage to do it I'll open a question. Thank you.

Comment: @RuiMochila would you be able to elaborate on how to fix this? I've tried to do `mTextView.requestFocus();` and I've also tried `mTextView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)` in the `onResume()` method, but nothing occurs in either case.

Comment: @ChrisCM You should write a blog post about Accessibility in Android. I would love to read about the best practices. Things like, should we announce toolbar title automatically or let the system handle it, or what you mentioned above about the focus. In my case, I have an EditText and it takes the focus. I prefer Toolbar Title to consume it

Comment: why do we need a postdelayed

Comment: It makes sense to tackle this in the Activity lifecycle vs the View lifecycle. However, Activity doesn't have the proper callback to facilitate this without a delay, as any attempt to focus elements immediately after Activity lifecycle events will fail, because the Accessibility Tree isn't properly attached yet. Note: As of Feb 12, 2015 this was certainly true. That was a long time ago in Android years.

Comment: Great topic! I was wondering myself, how do users with visual impairments react to timed things on the screen? For example, the Snackbar! If the UI is a looong list of stuff and suddenly the snackbar shows up - I'm betting that everyone using accessibility is going to miss that info because by the time they swipe right enough to focus on the snackbar, it's long gone into the sunset. Is snackbar terrible for accessibility ?

Comment: Snackbar is an excellent patter to replace Toast messages, but it is not a pattern I would use abundantly in my own designs. Hope that made sense!

Comment: I would like to add that the "Forcing focus on Activity load to be anywhere but at the top bar is always (okay, always should almost never be said), but really, just don't do it." is not actually true. In some cases (and more recent books on the subject) the recommended approach is "it depends". Context is the king, and focusing a screen in a "back arrow" that says "Back" is not better than providing appropriate "talkback" context and proper content descriptions.

Answer (score 21):

Recently I had the same problem. I created an Android extension function to focus a view that was not focused with a `postDelayed` like the other solutions proposed;

```
sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
```

But I had another scenario where it didn't work. However, I got it to work with this:

```
fun View.accessibilityFocus(): View {
    this.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null)
    this.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED)
    return this
}
```

Comment: For anyone else having the same problem ... I found doing the regular sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) wasn't working with Samsung Voice Assistant on Android 10 (strangely 9 and below fine ....)

However this other solution was the only thing that would work on that device. Kudos Gilberto, many thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem because for consistent navigation we wanted the newly opened page's title to be selected.
The problem was that the screen reader was selecting the first header button at the top left of my pages and not the title.

I had a `myRootView` variable for the whole view and a `myTitleView` variable for the title text view.

The solution that ChrisCM proposed for getting accessibility focused on the right view definitely helped me:

```
myTitleView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
```

However I still had the problem that calling this code on app start had no effect because the screen reader was not ready yet, and the solution proposed for "waiting for talkback to be available" of waiting 5 full seconds was not something I wanted to do because by then, the user might already be using the interface and their selection would be interrupted by the automatic focus.

I noticed that on app open, the top left header button was systematically selected by accessibility, so I wrote a class to listen on that selection and trigger my own selection right after.

Here is the code of the class in question:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.AccessibilityDelegate;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public abstract class OnFirstAccessibilityFocusRunner extends AccessibilityDelegate implements Runnable {
    @NonNull
    private final View rootView;
    private boolean hasAlreadyRun = false;

    public OnFirstAccessibilityFocusRunner(@NonNull final View _rootView) {
        rootView = _rootView;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        rootView.setAccessibilityDelegate(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(@Nullable final ViewGroup host, @Nullable final View child,
        @Nullable final AccessibilityEvent event) {
        if (!hasAlreadyRun
            && event != null
            && event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED
        ) {
            hasAlreadyRun = true;
            rootView.setAccessibilityDelegate(null);
            run();
        }
        return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(host, child, event);
    }
}
```

Then I use the code like this (for example in the onPostResume method of the Activity):

```
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    new OnFirstAccessibilityFocusRunner(myRootView) {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myTitleView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
        }
    };
}
```

It took me a few hours to figure out how to instantly get the focus to the right view, I hope this helps others too!

Answer (score 3):

`lifecycleScope` is available in the activity. No need to bind delay with any overridden method.

```
private fun View.focusAccessibility() = lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
    delay(300)
    this@focusAccessibility.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null)
}
```

Comment: this answer is saved a dev's sleepy eyes... thank you so much man!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: Seems that some views intercepting the accessibility focus (like RecyclerView, PreferenceFragmentCompat) and my solution is kind of "waiting talkback to be available".

Kotlin KTX provide the way to execute smth when view is ready for showing to user and Coroutine can help with delay. It isn't the best way but fast and simple.

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
      delay(300)
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { customView.doOnLayout {it.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) }}
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use coroutines in this way. There's `View#postDelayed`, which works fine.