# Talkback Accessbility issue when fragments change

Tags: android, talkback

Hey I am implementing accessibility feature in my current app.

Here is the problem I am facing now.

I have welcome cards where each welcome card has heading, description on the top and small note at bottom and I am placing these welcome cards inside the viewpager which is attached to the activity and activity contains circle indicator and one small image on the bottom.

now when i move fragments one by one sometimes it reads the previous fragment content (like heading or description or note)  inside the visible fragment.

I want to remove the current focus of the fragment(old) when new fragment(new) comes into the screen. and when user swipes it should read the current fragment content which is focused.

please help me ..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some one please answer to this question

Comment: you can't do anything to prevent it .. the only way to avoid errors is that you have to set check of null for objects for fragments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Set TalkBack accessibility focus to a specific view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472985/android-set-talkback-accessibility-focus-to-a-specific-view)