# Flutter: How to get accessibility focus to custom appbar

Tags: flutter, material-design, accessibility, talkback

If you use the default Material scaffold with the default appbar, and you open your app using TalkBack, the accessibility focus moves automatically to the first item in the appbar (usually, the "Back" button).

I would like my appbar to be taller than the default, so I've created a custom one and pass it to the scaffold:

```
class CustomAppbar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 120,
      child: Semantics(
        focused: true,
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Test'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(120);
}
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppbar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            _buildContent(),
          ]),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The problem is, **if I don't use the default AppBar, I can't move the focus to the first button**, even if I wrap it with Semantics.

How is the default Scaffold handling the automatic focus? I've searched in the code and couldn't find it.

Comment: Try `FocusNode` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html

Comment: FocusNode is not the same as Semantic focus.

Comment: I was aware of that "solution", per this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57273232/move-accessibility-focus-programmatically but it seems like a hack. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Please see  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/semantics/SemanticsNode-class.html. You can use `visitChildren` method to focus an item programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your AppBar with a Semantic node and set `focused:true`.

Read more here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/semantics/SemanticsProperties/focused.html

Answer (score 0):

So flutter provides a widget `PreferredSize` to us in which we can override its height and width, I solved my problem in this way

```
 Widget appBar() {
        return PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120.0),
          child: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 16,
                  right: 16,
                  top: 16,
                  bottom: 16
                ),
                child: Container(
                  // make any type of view
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: My example code already implemented that widget. The problem is not obtaining a custom height, it's keeping the accessibility features.