# In TextFormField the maxLength is getting the Accessibility Focus - why?

Tags: android, flutter, accessibility, semantics, talkback

It's a flutter app we are dealing with and I had this issue on Android with Talkback.

I'm having a simple TextFormField with given maxLength parameter. When swiping through the page,  the maxLength (max length of input string) below the textfield is getting the accessibility focus from talkback. When I double tap to trigger the tap action I can edit the textfield though.

When I wrap the TextFormField with a MergeSemantics, the whole thing gets the AccessibilityFocus along with the maxLength display like I wished it would. But then I can't manipulate the Semantics label of the TextFormField when I use the MergeSemantics Widget. What is the correct solution to manipulate/edit the Semantics of the TextFormField with maxLength set?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472985/android-set-talkback-accessibility-focus-to-a-specific-view or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080579/android-textfield-set-focus-soft-input-programmatically

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS unfortunately no, because I'm using the flutter framework, I should've had it emphasized :/