# sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED) not working

Tags: android, accessibility

I want to put accessibility focus on the header. For that I tried with the following code:

```
private fun headerFocus() {
    val task = Runnable {
        binding.headerInterbank.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED)
    }

    val worker: ScheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

    worker.schedule(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

I am calling to this method on fragment onViewCreated event. Anyway I had to add the worker because the binding was giving me an error. But the main issue here is that sendAccessibilityEvent is not working and the header is not focused after calling to it.

I tried to do as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472985/android-set-talkback-accessibility-focus-to-a-specific-view) and also tried with other solutions like

```
this.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS, null)
this.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED)
```